# What happens when I place an object of certain temperature in space ? Does it loose its entire heat energy?

Tags: temperature, space, thermal-radiation, vacuum, cryogenics

Can i obtain absolute zero temperature this way?

And let's assume there is no cosmic microwave background and also assume that there is a way to shield the object from any heat source, such as the sun.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If (hypothetically) you could find a far off region of space where there is no radiation of any sort, and you place a hot object there, then it would radiate away its heat and gain no heat back from its surroundings. The rate of radiation would gradually decrease but eventually it would lose its last photon and enter a ground state of absolute zero temperature.

There are some caveats, firstly if protons are unstable (we dont know) then there is no real ground state since eventually any atoms would decay to radiated particles.

secondly, it would not be possible to observe the ground state since to do so would require approaching it with some probe that would itself be warm so that heat was transferred to your object. You might therefore argue that the object can never reach its pure ground state and always remains in a mixed state or quantum supposition of states so it never reaches absolute zero. There is a philosophical debate to be had about what can be said to really happen in this situation.

In practice of course you can not find such a region of space since it would itself have to be at absolute zero temperature. You cannot shield something perfectly from external heat because the material you would use for the shield would itself have to be at zero temperature to work perfectly. You can therefore only use refrigeration methods to try and extract heat but this process is never perfect and absolute zero is never achieved. In other words you cant get something to absolute zero temperature unless everything around it can be brought to zero temperature first. It is a chicken and egg situation.

Answer (score 3):

Any object that approximates a black body (which means pretty much everything) radiates heat according to the [Stefan-Boltzmann law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_law):

$$ W = \sigma T^4 $$

If we could insulate the object from all incoming radiation (which is impossible, but let's go with it for the sake of this question) the change of temperature with time would be given by:

$$ C \frac{dT}{dt} = \sigma T^4 $$

where $C$ is the specific heat of the object. If we assume $C$ is independant of temperature we can solve this equation to give:

$$ T(t) = \sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{\frac{3\sigma}{C}t - \frac{1}{T_0^3}}} $$

where $T_0$ is the initial temperature of the object at time $t = 0$. For large $t$ we have the approximate relationship between temperature and time:

$$ T \propto \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{t}} $$

So as $t \rightarrow \infty$ the temperature will approach zero asymptotically. You cannot achieve absolute zero unless you're willing to wait an infinite time.

Answer (score 1):

There are, of course, 3 mechanisms for heat transfer - conduction, convection and radiation. So isolated in vacuum convection and conduction will play no role (provided, of course, the vacuum is perfect, which is a pretty good assumption for space, but not quite reality).

I am guessing from your question that no radiation hits the object in your thought experiment so it cannot be warmed.

If the surface of the object is 'black', meaning that it can emit and absorb any wavelength of light then it will emit radiation and loose heat until its temperature is zero or very close to zero. This is because any body above absolute zero will emit radiation.

[A practical thing related to this is that in real experiments with cold heads that go down to 10 K or 4 K or lower it is very important to shield the cold head from external radiation sources that would heat up.]

Answer (score 0):

Well, progress in science goes on and on and if one forgets the space set up there exists a positive answer to part of the question "Can i obtain absolute zero temperature ..."

Absolute zero of temperature and temperature itself are thermodynamic quantities, from classical physics. [Quantum mechanics has surprises](http://www.nature.com/news/quantum-gas-goes-below-absolute-zero-1.12146)

> Lord Kelvin defined the absolute temperature scale in the mid-1800s in such a way that nothing could be colder than absolute zero. Physicists later realized that the absolute temperature of a gas is related to the average energy of its particles. Absolute zero corresponds to the theoretical state in which particles have no energy at all, and higher temperatures correspond to higher average energies.
>
> However, by the 1950s, physicists working with more exotic systems began to realise that this isn't always true: Technically, you read off the temperature of a system from a graph that plots the probabilities of its particles being found with certain energies. Normally, most particles have average or near-average energies, with only a few particles zipping around at higher energies. In theory, if the situation is reversed, with more particles having higher, rather than lower, energies, the plot would flip over and the sign of the temperature would change from a positive to a negative absolute temperature, explains Ulrich Schneider, a physicist at the Ludwig Maximilian University in Munich, Germany.
>
> Schneider and his colleagues reached such sub-absolute-zero temperatures with an ultracold quantum gas made up of potassium atoms. Using lasers and magnetic fields, they kept the individual atoms in a lattice arrangement. At positive temperatures, the atoms repel, making the configuration stable. The team then quickly adjusted the magnetic fields, causing the atoms to attract rather than repel each other. “This suddenly shifts the atoms from their most stable, lowest-energy state to the highest possible energy state, before they can react,” says Schneider. “It’s like walking through a valley, then instantly finding yourself on the mountain peak.”
>
> At positive temperatures, such a reversal would be unstable and the atoms would collapse inwards. But the team also adjusted the trapping laser field to make it more energetically favourable for the atoms to stick in their positions. This result, described today in Science1, marks the gas’s transition from just above absolute zero to a few billionths of a Kelvin below absolute zero.

Well, billionths of a Kelvin but certainly crossed T=0.